# Overlay SKScene on SKScene

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

Yes, I know what you're thinking... but this is not a duplicate..

I have 2 scenes, gameScene and menuScene. I want to overlay the menuScene over the gameScene. I know you can't present 2 scenes at once and I looked at solutions, they all suggest setting the menuScene as SKNode and not SKScene.

### The problem is that I need my menuScene to be SKScene because I'm using the SKCameraNode(which is not available in SKNode)...

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Step back and explain your problem,  I think your approach is off

Comment: Why does menuScene need to know a camera?

Comment: I made a scrollview using the camera... @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Its a scrollview where you select levels

Comment: it is not really a scroll view, you are just calling it this

Comment: You can always attach menu scene directly to the camera, and implement scroll there

Comment: yes, i just call it scrollview

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: camera.addChild(menu),  to scroll just change menu.position

Comment: okay i will give it a try

Comment: there are oldschool ways to make a camera without SKCameraNode.. search for Camera questions from 2014-2015 .

Answer (score 4):

Trust me , you can't. The approach that you should have against these situations is to think about the hierarchy and roles (look to the figure below)

So, say that, if you have now two `SKScene` (*menuScene* and *gameScene*)  don't throw to the trash your *menuScene* (you can present it in other situations like the end of the game where you present another scene, your gameOver scene or your *menuScene* for example) , you could develop a new `SKNode` as a child of your *gameScene* and use the *gameScene* camera to handle your new *menuNode*. About your *gameScene* you could move your game objects to a node child and put this node in pause, meanwhile your menu is in action..

[image]

Comment: i tried it out and it didn't work, it moves the whole gameScene even if one node is paused.

Comment: Have you create your new menuNode and superimposed it to all the others?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an old-school camera without SKCameraNode. Apple explains how here, and you can also look at 'how to create camera' in many 2d game engines are similar to this explanation:

(scroll down a bit for camera stuff)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html

( you can use this to translate to swift if needed: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/ )

Still, a better solution may just be to slightly redesign how your scenes are layed out and interacted with :)

Answer (score 0):

Let each `SKScene` be presented by a different `SKView`.

Then you may do whatever you wish with the `SKView`s.
You may for instance stack the `SKView`s, one on top of the other.

You can stack the `SKView`s either by adding one as a subview of the other.
Or you can stack them by adding them all as subviews of the same parent view.